# Criteria representation for the following HQL

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I Have the below HQL for thee following sql..

the SQL ....

```
SELECT * FROM POS_took WHERE DELETEDDATE IS NOT NULL
```

and it corresponding HQL is...

```
session.createQuery("from postook where deleted is not null")
```

and the java Entity class is ...

```
class postook
{

//all the properties defined here 

private DateTime deleted;

//and it corresponding setters and getters is defined.
```

Now please advise the equivalent criteria representation of the above HQL

Answer (score 2):

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(postook.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("deleted"));
```

see more details http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch12.html